# Searching a list of numbers for a specific pattern

Tags: python

I am working with Project Euler problem [51](http://projecteuler.net/problem=51) and I am trying to solve it by searching a list of primes. I have begun by trying to find the example candidate (56003).

I have reduced the problem to: First restrict attention to primes with a certain number of digits. F.ex. I start by looking at 5 digit primes which I have in an array.

Denote the prime with **ABCDE**. Just replacing one digit: ***BCDE** gives rise to 5C1=5 pattern candidates: **A*CDE** etc. Replacing two digits: ****CDE** gives rise to 5C2=10 pattern candidates. Etc up to replacing 4 digits: ****E, which gives rise to 5C4 pattern candidates.

So as an example, I have this list of numbers

```
s = ['55967', '56003', '56113', '56081', '56333', '56093', '58091']
```

And say I want to search for the **AB**E** pattern: Then I would want the search function to find: 56003, 56113 and 5633.

My problem is that I don't know how to accomplish that. I have read some about Regular Expressions, but concluded with that RE's only makes my brain hurt.

Thank you

Comment: This is a most easily solved through regular expression.  I suggest playing around with a tool like rubular http://rubular.com/ and getting more familiar with them.  There are solutions you could hack together if there are only a few things you're looking for, but in general regular expressions are your best bet.

Edit: You should also consider other approaches to that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regular expression snippet should work for your problem.

```
import re
s = ['55967', '56003', '56113', '56081', '56333', '56093', '58091']
patt_s = re.compile('(56\d\d3)')
for s_nr in s:
    matched_re = re.search(patt_s, s_nr)
    if matched_re:
        print matched_re.group(0)
```

Output: 
56003
56113
56333
56093

However, you do need to read up on regular expressions and try out simple ones or modify the one above to customize for other situations! At least they are more or less the same across many different languages.

Comment: Thank you, but that procedure wouldn't be very practical in my case since to match the AB**E pattern I need to make 9*10*10=900 regular expressions..? Also I forgot to mention that the wildcards ** denotes two identical digits, e.g. 11, or 22.